# How Chocolatey should be prepared using NPM working environment?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install, chocolatey

Previously installed packages should be removed? What should be the local path and environment variables? Any of these topics, there are suggestions for Windows?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking...perhaps you could formulate the question better with some context.

Comment: Ok, it's a bit complicated, I want to create a work environment using npm to Chocolatey.

Comment: That doesn't sound that complicated, but it would be best if your question was a bit longer and explained the context. For an example of how to formulate your question, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36202269/18475

Comment: Right now you've basically rapid fired 4 questions here without any context. It's hard to provide any reasonable response because you haven't identified your constraints, what you have tried, what you have found, etc.

Comment: In the example:http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/, there is someone who tries to as Windows?